# AngularJS not working on github pages

Tags: angularjs, github

this is my repository

https://github.com/devRena/chelseateam.github.io

and this is the github page

https://devrena.github.io/chelseateam.github.io/

i use http to take data from remote server. when i open my project in my pc all is ok, but when i upload these files on github can not take response data from the remote server. what happend and how to resolve the problem?

Comment: If you open the console you'll get the answer: *The page at 'https://devrena.github.io/chelseateam.github.io/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/searchplayers.php?t=Chelsea'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.*

Comment: Thank you very much!! I changed the url "http:://thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/searchplayers.php?t=Chelsea" to "https:://thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/searchplayers.php?t=Chelsea" and is working now

Comment: Sorry not working. I opened one time and i have the same problem again. Can i resolve the problem?

Comment: I opened your page, same error cuz JS was loaded from cache. I cleared the cache and it worked (I pressed Shift+F5)

Comment: Thanks for your help all is perfect now :)